# How do I install modernizr 3 via rails-assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower, modernizr

modernizr 2 was easy to install from [rails-assets](https://rails-assets.org/).

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails-assets-modernizr'
# application.js
//= require modernizr
```

However, the modernizr 3 docs say:

> A lot has changed since the last version of Modernizr. There no longer is a single, base modernizr.js file. Instead, just head over to the Download page as you could have previously, and select the features you want to use in your project. 
>   https://modernizr.com/docs/

This makes it sound like I can't get modernizr 3 from rails-assets anymore. Is this true?

As expected, if I try to install modernizr 3 from rails-assets I get:

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred ...

  couldn't find file 'modernizr' ...
  app/assets/javascripts/application.js:20
```

Comment: [Rails Assets website](https://rails-assets.org/) indicates that latest version available for `modernizr` is `3.0.0`. Have you tried installing it?

Comment: Yes, re: "Rails Assets website indicates that latest version available for modernizr is 3.0.0. Have you tried installing it?"

Comment: Alright, thanks for cooperation. Yes, apparently [the corresponding Bower component](https://github.com/components/modernizr) (24 days since last release) hasn't yet been updated to work with the latest release of Modernizr (10 days since). Filing an issue may speed up the process. Since the answer to this question may quickly become out-of-date, I don't see a reason to publish a full-fledged answer. I think we should wait for a little while.

Comment: the bower package is not an official one, and predicated on the concept of a modernizr file - which has been removed in 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get v3 to work. I down versioned to 2.8.3 like by changing my gemfile like this:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-respond'
  gem 'rails-assets-modernizr', '2.8.3'
end
```